# Apache serving assets from remote

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

I have a social web application in production, and I'm trying to strengthen my system, and development practices.  However, as the application has become more popular, I don't want to be downloading certain assets to my local machine just to have a local simprod.  (for example, images users have uploaded.)

I'm using Zend Framework, and my local is set up using a vhost definition on my local box.  I'm not an Apache expert, but I have tried a few things.

#### Goal

`I need to serve certain assets from my remote server when they are requested by the local application`

Inside my `<VirtualHost>` config, I've been trying:

```
Alias images/users http://www.productionsite.com/images/users
```

but doesn't seem to work.  The assets in question are underneath the `/public` directory, so ZF isn't rewrite those requests.  I've also tried it inside the local `.htaccess`

I suppose I could write a config into `application.ini` for this asset path, but I'd have to refactor more code than it's really worth, as the app is undergoing a rewrite to ZF2.

How can I do this using apache instead of ZF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I should have been using `Redirect` instead of `Alias`.  It also should be noted that adding a trailing a backslash to both the request path and the redirect path is critical for this specific situation, as it improperly match requests and call the incorrect path without it.

You also need to ensure that a few options are set... if not for the app, then at very least on the `<Directory`, and this configuration needs to be declared **after** the `Redirect` command.

This is made possible by the `rewrite_module` apache module, so I had to make sure it was enabled.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin a@a.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/app/public"
  ServerName www.local.website.com
  ..other non-relevant settings
  Redirect /images/users/ http://bnboomer.com/images/users/
  <Directory "c:/wamp/www/app/public/images/users" >
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you have your local apache set up in a secure fashion, the `<Directory>` rules listed will be important in making this work.  If you just use the default wamp options however, it appears WAMP/MAMP/LAMP installs have those options configured in a directory block for the www directory already in the `.conf`, and as such wouldn't necessarily need to be defined again in order for this to work properly.

Note:  If you have several different machines that you use on the same network as personal 'local' machines, and use apache as a proxy, it's important to lock those options down.  Apache docs has an article on [URL Mapping](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html) that I found to be more helpful than even the rewrite or alias docs.

**Note:**  Before anyone downvotes me for answering my own question... I needed the solution fast, and the question garnered no views, so I spent several hours surfing the docs and boning up.  I considered deleting the question, but I feel it may hold value for the community, so I decided to leave it... and answer it instead.